# how to cache remote view?

Tags: android

i need to know if is it possible to cache layout remote view ?

if so how i can cache or clean the cache is there any example here i tried to google it i could't find an example how to cache layout remote view

for example how to cache this notification progress !

thank you for your time

```
      updateTask = this;

      //setup notification ID and information
      Random r = new Random();
      NOTIFICATION_ID  = r.nextInt(80-65) + 1;
      NOTIFICATION_ID++;

      int icon = R.drawable.icon;
      long when = System.currentTimeMillis();

      notification = new Notification(icon, getString(R.string.app_name), when);
      contentView = new RemoteViews(getPackageName(), R.layout.custom_notification);
      contentView.setTextViewText(R.id.text, "cool"+NOTIFICATION_ID);

      notification.contentView = contentView;

      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_NO_CLEAR;
      notification.flags |= Notification.FLAG_ONGOING_EVENT;



      Intent notificationIntent = new Intent();

      notificationIntent.setFlags(Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK | Intent.FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TOP);
      notificationIntent.setAction(Intent.ACTION_MAIN);
      PendingIntent contentIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(BabupMain.this, 0, notificationIntent, 0);

      notification.contentIntent = contentIntent;


      mNotificationManager.notify(NOTIFICATION_ID, notification);
```

Comment: chekc this: Custom Notification Layouts with Button click --> http://dj-android.blogspot.in/2013/04/android-notifications.html

Comment: Thank you bro i already tried this but the progress wont update in AsyncTask , notification progress updated in AsyncTask only if i use custom layout remote view , but its leak the memory so I've added switch case for progress to prevent notification to cost memory leak and freeze the notifications bar , it work so far but i need to cache notification remote view is it possible ?